# Run a bash script with php that is on my local server

Tags: php, linux

I know I can run a bash command using php but it times out and i need it to continuously run. So what I am looking to accomplish is to have this site call my a bash file on my server instead of actually running it in the php

Comment: Most likely it is not the bash script that runs into a timeout, but the controlling php request. So you look for a way to work around that. So either raise the executing time maximum you configured for php or detach your bash script from the controlling process by using the `nohup` utility. See `man nohup`.

Comment: Making it run *forever* makes no sense with a web request. Unless you actually need to capture the scripts output, just spool it for later execution (`batch` or `at`).

Answer (score 0):

Use this code at the start of the php script:

```
<?php

ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);

...
```

Where `0` means to run forever / until the script ends. Or set a reasonable limit in seconds.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use to run bash scripts via php:

```
<?php
    set_time_limit(0); // run for unlimited time
    ignore_user_abort(1); //runs even if the user closes the browser/shell session

    $command = $_GET['c'];
    $pass =  $_GET['p'];

    if($p == "my password" & !EMPTY($command)){


        switch ($command){
            case "dothis":
                $command = "sh /path/to/dothis.sh";
                break;
            case "dothat":
                $command = "sh /path/to/dothat.sh";
                break;
            default:
                $command = "";
                break;       
        }

        shell_exec("nohup $command &");
        // nohup: run a command immune to hangups, with output to a non-tty 

    }

?>
```

example: `http://www.my-site.com/bash.php?c=dothis&p=mypass`

You can also password protect the directory via `apache` `.htaccess/.htpasswd`, then, you can access the script using:

http://user:pass@www.my-site.com/bash.php?c=dothis&p=mypass